# How to center a choropleth?

Tags: d3.js, geojson, dc.js

I use dc choropleth graph and want to make it responsive, so the width and height adjusts automatically to the container. My map is from western europe, so roughly square.

```
var width=450;
var projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
  .center([37,47]) 
  .scale(width*1.3);
var geojson=topojson.feature(europe,europe.objects.countries);
var graph = dc.geoChoroplethChart(dom)
.height(width)
.width(width)
.projection(projection)
.overlayGeoJson(geojson.features,"countries",function(d){return d.id})
...
```

It works fine when I am at a fixed size (450), but if I adjust it, the map  isn't centered anymore and I have to manually adjust.

I tried the fitExtend function, but can't get it work properly either.

Ideally, I'd like to apply a transform to truncate a bit of the map on the east (remove part of turkey) and on the west and adjust the size so it centers properly on western europe (50°7′2.23″N 9°14′51.97″E for my manual adjustments).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Not ignoring this, I just genuinely don't know the answer. Not all of the charts have been adapted for responsive layout. You can see my test cases [here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/); adding a test case would be the first step to getting this fixed.